# Installed ubuntu 14.04 and grub is not showing windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

tried grub update and boot-repair but none working.
this is the link which boot repair gave me
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10923998/

Comment: Your sda2 has changed from NTFS to FAT32 and now also has some syslinux boot files and a command com. It need to be NTFS so that bootmgr & BCD are used. You cannot modify/repair main install to directly boot as Windows only boots from primary partitions and your main install is in sda6. It might be easier to backup bootmgr & BCD (and folders) and reformat sda2. But make sure you have a working Windows repair CD or flash drive. You may just able to change (not reformat) format back to NTFS.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/271323/windows-missing-from-grub-menu

Comment: @oldfred Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 1):

Windows only boots from primary NTFS partitions with the boot flag. Since your install is in sda6 a logical partition, you cannot repair it directly to be bootable. You have to have a primary partition with bootmgr & BCD (and other files not normally shown in Summary repport).

You need to convert sda2 back to NTFS. It also shows some old DOS type boot files, so you must have converted it. But it has your bootmgr & BCD and boot flag, so it must have been your NTFS boot partition.

You may be able to use Disks or Disk Utility to just convert to NTFS or 07 type, but then may need to restore backup PBR or partition boot sector using testdisk. If you reformat be sure to first backup bootmgr, BCD & other Windows boot files.

Best to have a Windows repairCD or flash drive as then you can run those repairs.

And best to have Windows on primary partitions and Linux on the logical partitions. Linux does not care, but Windows really only likes primary NTFS partitions.

Comment: Going through my "schmucks" answers that didn't get any upvotes...  So finally you got one!  ;-)

Comment: I do not know how this is considered a duplicate, but it is a bit unique with Windows in an extended partition and what looked like boot partition converted to FAT. But not many others will have similar issue. And references to Windows with UEFI would not relate at all.

Comment: [The problem with committees](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynq1x.png)  ;-)  You could edit the question to make it more specific to your answer, drop into the chat room and rally everyone to vote to re-open...